# Rails app on JRuby 1.7.19 in Nailgun mode does not start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

Using JRuby 1.7.19, I run `jruby --ng-server`, and then `rails c` with `JRUBY_OPTS="--ng"` and it just sits there with no output and no progress. Other ruby scripts work fine. It's just rails that sits there and does nothing like it's frozen.

---

### Note

This question is almost exactly the same as
[Rails app on JRuby 1.7 in Nailgun mode does not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213679/rails-app-on-jruby-1-7-in-nailgun-mode-does-not-start)

However, I am now on I am .12 version in the future and this still does not work. Yet the question is marked as solved. I followed the exact steps listed in the accepted answer to no avail.